# In C, modify the target of a pointer to an array of pointers when passed as argument to a function

Tags: c, pointers

I want a function that returns the content of a given directory. For this, I am using [`scandir`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Scanning-Directory-Content.html#Scanning-Directory-Content) from `dirent.h`. The code below compiles successfully (gcc -Wall test.c), but the last printf leads to a segmentation fault. It means that the "eps" structure (a pointer to an array of pointers to dirent structures) is still empty after the function: how can I fix this?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

static int myselector(const struct dirent * dir_entry)
{
  char * pch = strstr(dir_entry->d_name, ".");
  return pch == NULL ? 1 : 0;
}

int list_dir(char * dirname, struct dirent ** eps)
{
  int nbfiles = scandir(dirname, &eps, myselector, alphasort);
  if(nbfiles > 0)
  {
    printf("inside function: %s\n", eps[0]->d_name);
    return 1;
  }
  else
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int status = 0;
  struct dirent ** eps = NULL;
  status = list_dir("/home", eps);
  if (status)
  {
    puts("ok");
    printf("outside function: %s\n", eps[0]->d_name);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why's it called `eps`? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your pointer has changed, and you're looking at the wrong thing in `main()` :)

You're passing a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to `scandir()`. it's changing what the pointer to a pointer is pointing at (I know, that hurts to read ... ).

Because you're calling `scandir()` with `&eps` in your function, you lose that change outside of the function. The value of `eps` has changed inside your function.

To better understand this, in your current function wrap the `scandir()` call with `printf()` statements showing you what the value contained in `eps` is:

```
...
printf("%p\n", eps);
int nbfiles = scandir(dirname, &eps, myselector, alphasort);
printf("%p\n", eps);
...
```

To fix this change your function to:

```
int list_dir(char * dirname, struct dirent *** eps)
{
  int nbfiles = scandir(dirname, eps, myselector, alphasort);
  if(nbfiles != -1)
  {
    printf("inside function: %s\n", (*eps)[0]->d_name);
    return 1;
  }
  else
    return 0;
}
```

And call it as ...

```
status = list_dir("/home", &eps);
```

in `main()`. It will then work perfectly:

> broach@roach-VirtualBox:~$ ./test
>   inside function: broach
>   ok
>   outside function: broach

Comment: thanks, clear answer on a typical "pointer-to-pointer-to..." example... I need to engrave it in my head!

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be covering the case where `scandir` returns 0, i.e., empty directory. Return value of -1 is only for errors.

Comment: yes, I was a bit quick for this short example, it's fixed now.

Comment: No. The segfault is not due to the fact that the input directory can be empty, but rather to the fact that the "eps" structure is filled inside my "listd_dir" function, and then emptied once the function is finished. And I don't know how to prevent this.

Comment: See my answer - the problem is that the pointer to the `dirent` stricture gets reassigned.

Answer (score 1):

Make list_dir take `struct dirent ***` instead of `struct dirent **`, get rid of the `&` operator in the scandir() call, and add it to the list_dir() call from main.
The first lines of list_dir() become:

```
int list_dir(char * dirname, struct dirent *** eps)
{
  int nbfiles = scandir(dirname, eps, myselector, alphasort);
```

and the list_dir() call in main becomes:

```
status = list_dir("/home", &eps);
```

That way list_dir() can let scandir() modify `eps` from main() via its address, instead of modifying the argument, on the stack, passed to list_dir().

Comment: perfect, thanks! (and sorry not to choose your answer, Brian Roach was quicker from a few minutes ;)