# In C, how to initialize a pointer-to-pointers from inside a function?

Tags: c, pointers

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374445/in-c-modify-the-target-of-a-pointer-to-an-array-of-pointers-when-passed-as-argum/7374552#7374552), I made a simple example to be sure I properly understood:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int x;
} data;

void fill_data (data *** ptr_all, int l)
{
  int i = 0;
  *ptr_all = (data**) calloc(l, sizeof(data));
  if ((*ptr_all) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "error: can't allocate memory");
    abort();
  }
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
  {
    data * d = (data*) calloc(1, sizeof(data));
    if (d == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "error: can't allocate memory for %i-th data", i+1);
      abort();
    }
    d->x = i;
    (*ptr_all)[i] = d;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 0, l = 5;
  data ** all = NULL;

  fill_data (&all, l);

  for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
  {
    printf("%i\n", all[i]->x);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, after compiling and running it, I see that the first element is wrong:

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
$ ~/bin/a.out 
161276080
1
2
3
4
```

I can see that in my function `fill_data` I don't initialize ptr_all, but only *ptr_all, and this may be the cause of the problem. But how should I do?

Comment: Seems to work fine http://www.ideone.com/ZPU2W

Comment: ptr_all doesn't need to be assigned to in fill_data because its value is already &all. I think your first calloc should have `sizeof(data*)`

Comment: I'm not even going to try and answer this question, but one advice: when you think you need pointers-to-pointers-to-pointers, you've probably got the design wrong. Pointers to pointers should suffice for almost all purposes.

Comment: It appears to work OK on a 32 bit OS but not on a 64 bit (LP64) OS. See answer below.

Comment: I upvoted Paul R's answer below because it's correct.  In future, you may want to break things down a little bit more.  For example, in this case, create a local variable data ** all and then assign it to *ptr_all before exiting the function.  While I've written code with seven or eight levels of indirection in C, it's always been in the counting that I've had problems.  Breaking it up into pieces that only manage a simple structure makes it much more obvious when you've made a mistake.  And use a debugger so you can see what the memory actually looks like. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
*ptr_all = (data**) calloc(l, sizeof(data));
```

to:

```
*ptr_all = (data**) calloc(l, sizeof(data*));
```

You're allocating `l` ints whereas you need to be allocating `l` pointers. You're almost certainly building and running this on a 64 bit OS (where `sizeof(void *) > sizeof(int)`), otherwise this bug would have remained dormant.